# How to get two key's levels in a dict using python's get() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check two key's levels in a dict and get it's or a default value
Something like:

```
a.get('b.c', x)
```

Is there an easy and optimal way for that?

Comment: Something like this `a.get('b', {}).get('c', x)` ?

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.get('b', {'c': x}).get('c', x)
```

Edit: @andrej-kesely implementation `a.get('b', {}).get('c', x)` suits better.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function for that, like:

```
_dummy = object()

def rec_get(dct, *args, default=None):
    for arg in args:
        dct = dct.get(arg, _dummy)
        if dct is _dummy:
            return default
    return dct
```

Then you can call this like:

```
rec_get(my_dict, 'b', 'c', default=x)
```

for example:

```
>>> my_dict = { 'b' : { 'c': 4 }, 2 : { 'a': 3 } }
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 'b', 'c', default=None)
4
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 'b', 'a', default=None)  # returns None
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 'b', 'a', default=1425)
1425
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 'b', default=None)
{'c': 4}
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 2, default=None)
{'a': 3}
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 2, 'a', default=None)
3
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 2, 'b', default=6)
6
>>> rec_get(my_dict, 3, 'b', default=6)
6
```

this allows you to query dictionaries where the keys are not per se strings (integers, tuples, etc).

You can make queries that are arbitrary deep, and from the moment a key is not found, it will return the `default=...` value. It however does *not* take into account that it is possible that one of the intermediate dictionaries might not be a dictionary-like object. In that case, it might raise an `AttributeError`, or a `TypeError` if the `.get` attribute is not a function, or does not follow the parameter contracts.